# Creeping ActiveX button

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2013

Good day!

I have an ActiveX button (that is anchored in position based on the number of rows from the top) that runs VBA code to insert a specified number copied rows at a particular point. The code itself works fine, but the button "clones" itself and overlays itself in the position of the new lines even though I have set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Once the screen updating is enabled again, the screen refreshs and the clones disappear.

I have tracked it down to one line of code: `Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Once that line runs, the button is cloned.

For example, if I added 3 blank lines with this macro, the button looks like this once the command above executes until the subroutine is finished:

[image]

To make this more interesting, this behavior was NOT happening when I used Excel 2010. I upgraded to Excel 2013 the other day and now this problem is occurring.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a picture of what it looks like, but I don't have the reputation to post it.

Comment: Post a link to imgur and I can put the pic in for you

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I was able to gain the reputation I needed to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience similar behavior when Application.ScreenUpdating = False. I don't think there is really a good answer for this. There are just workarounds as far as I know.

You are likely pushing the button up or down with the insert and when Application.ScreenUpdating = False things still "sort of" update. If you want it to go away you could try a few things.

1. Set screenupdating to true before the insert and then back to false after the insert so you won't get your "clones".
2. Reposition the button after you insert.
3. Delete your buttons, insert, then redraw them.
4. Use less of your computer's resources between your insert and Application.ScreenUpdating = True by simplifying your code etc.

Or post the code (as simplified as possible, yet demonstrates the issue) that is executing between when you insert and when you Application.ScreenUpdating = True.

I hope that is helpful.